# special character renaming in php to underscores

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

What's a good way to rename all special characters collected in a form to be replaced with an underscore?

Here's an example of the special characters to be replaced:

```
[.!,;:@#$%^&*|()?/\\\<>] space tab CR NL
```

I am tying into a piece of software that is downloaded by a user, and in that software, the renaming convention is to replace any of the characters listed above with an underscore. And for my web based application to work properly, it needs to collect some information in a form field that is named exactly as the user put it in the software, and have the naming convention work right. So when the mp3 file gets uploaded, and the ajax call checks for a file, it will match exactly, thus tripping off the rest of the functionality.

Comment: You should use a white-list instead of a black-list. And a regex seems like the way to go, what do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there already:

```
$str = "Zebo's [Test]";
echo preg_replace("~['.!,;:@#$%^&*|()?/\\<> \t\r\n\[\]]~", "_", $str);
```

Output: `Zebo_s__Test_`

**Edited** to include `[`, `]`, and `'` properly - didn't realize you meant that you wanted to replace those.

By the way... You say you want to replace "all special characters," and that your list above is just an "example." You may want to do something broader, like this:

```
preg_replace("~[^A-Za-z0-9]~", "_", $str);
```

This would also catch characters like the backtick and other special characters, such as:

> `îõ§¶þäô

Comment: Doesn't seem to work Ed. Reason being if I did Zebo's [Test] the results would be as follows Zebo\'s_[Test]

Comment: See my edit to address this -- I didn't realize you wanted to replace the `[` and `]` characters; I thought you were simply showing us a character class.  Your example now produces `Zebo's__Test_`.

Comment: I had to add the ' in there as well, but that seems to do the trick.

Comment: Please see my note above; you may want to go broader and replace everything that isn't alphanumeric, so that all special characters get replaced.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$repl = preg_replace('~[.!,;:@#$%^&*|()?/\\\<>]~', '_', $str);
```

Comment: anubhava, when I run your test, using Zebo's [Test], I get the following: Zebo_'s_[Test]

Comment: But did you want space to be replaced also? Since you wrote `space tab CR NL`

Comment: Basically anything within that line as posted above, needs to be renamed to an underscore